# How to get a particular class from n number of classes, having a special starting with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, class

Let us take an example :

HTML :

```
 <span class="one two three c-four five">How To Choose The "c-four" Class Out Of All Five Classes</span>
```

I assume the javascript function would seem something like this :

```
choose("span");
```

This will choose out the class that has "c-" in front of it, but a thing this will choose out only a class. If there are two or more classes with "c-" then it will choose the last one as an overwrite over the first one.

So can this be done ? If yes how ?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: access class list then manipulate it.

Comment: I am new to javascript, can you show how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by selecting all "span" elements which have a class that contains `c-`, and then grab the last element from this collection. Then, by filtering the `classList` of this element, you can get an array of all the classes which begin with `"c-"`. You can then use `.pop()` to get the last occurrence of this element.

See example below:

```js
const choose = elem => {
  const classes = [...document.querySelectorAll(`${elem}[class*="c-"]`)].pop().classList;
  return [...classes].filter(str => str.startsWith("c-")).pop();
}

console.log(choose("span"));
```

```html
<span class="one two three c-four five">How To Choose The "c-four" Class Out Of All Five Classes</span>
```